# Display Driver + Firefox/IE/Edge + Windows 10 = Constant Freeze-Ups?

Tags: graphics-card, windows-10, intel-graphics, display-driver

Okay, so I just bought an Asus K501UX laptop with an i7 processor and a NVIDIA graphics card. Well, actually, I bought two of them, but the first one had to be returned. But they both have the same problem. Every time I'm on either Firefox, Internet Explorer, or Microsoft Edge, my graphics driver crashes.

I noticed that this is a really common problem, so I tried downloading all the new drivers, etc. Nada. TdrDelay didn't help either.

Soon I noticed that the driver that was malfunctioning wasn't the NVIDIA one, but the one that ran the less powerful Intel card. Disabling the Intel driver effectively fixes the problem, but it makes the computer somewhat slower and it decreases my resolution. Also, if I install a Microsoft Generic Display Adapter driver from 2006, then it fixes the problem also, but once again, major slowdown.

Now what's odd is that Chrome NEVER crashes! It runs about as fast as any of the other browsers but the graphics card never stops responding. So Firefox and IE and Edge crash but not Chrome. And the crashes tend to happen mostly when there's an HTML5 canvas somewhere on the page. Weird.

Any suggestions? Is this a browser compatibility issue? Or is there something wrong with the Intel HD Graphics 520 card I'm using?

If anybody has a compatible driver for my Intel card that would fix this issue, that would be great. Thx!

Oh, and yes - I'm aware that I can sorta fix the problem by turning off hardware acceleration in these browsers. But this slows them down significantly, so I'd rather just fix the problem the right way. :P

Comment: in the Firefox/IE options, select software rendering/disable HW acceleration.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I know, but that drastically decreases their speed. There should be a way to fix the driver so that I don't have to ditch it completely. Besides, I'm pretty sure Chrome uses hardware acceleration and it doesn't have any problems.

Comment: disable the automatic driver update and try different Intel HD and nVIDIA driver versions.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I've already done that, I can't find an Intel HD driver that works. If I try to roll back too far it just says it's incompatible.

Comment: Would someone mind to explain the downvote? I don't see what is wrong with this question, it's a legit question...

Comment: open the nvidia driver options and look if you can force the usage of the nVIDIA GPU for edge, FF or IE. Does this fix it?